# Foundation 5 sticky footer (working example but has bugs to iron out)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

This has been asked before and now i also ask it, because i havent found a working cross browser example.

Currently i am looking into a cross platform sticky footer, but unfurtiantly i am having a bug i cant quite get my head around (see image at the end)

http://mnrb.dk/template-2-test/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="row possible-width" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h1>A row in a div</h1>

        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row full-width margin-reset" id="copyright">
            <footer>
                <div class="row possible-width margin-reset">
                    <h1>Le sticky footer</h1>
                    <h2>h2 test</h2>
                    <h3>h3 test</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="row full-width margin-reset">
                    <div class="row possible-width">
                        <p class="padding-reset margin-reset">&copy; 2015 <span>Spaceholder</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>

</div>

<!-- Style site js -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/adjust-classes.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
/*###############*/
/*Global settings*/
/*###############*/
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}


/*###########################*/
/*Custom foundation 5 classes*/
/*###########################*/
/*Adjust row width*/
.row.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.row.possible-width, hr.possible-width {
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 75%;
}

/*#####################*/
/*Sticky footer - Setup*/
/*#####################*/
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#wrapper > div:last-of-type {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex-grow: 1;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;

-webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
-ms-flex-negative: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;

-webkit-flex-basis: auto;
-ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
flex-basis: auto;

    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#copyright footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    background-color: hsl(195, 100%, 29%);
}

#copyright footer * {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

/*Second div in footer*/
#copyright footer > div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 13%);
    height: 50px !important;
}

#copyright footer div:nth-child(1), #copyright footer div:nth-child(2) > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#copyright footer > div:nth-child(2) p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: hsl(26, 0%, 60%);
}

#copyright footer div:nth-child(2) p span {
    color: hsl(26, 0%, 40%);
}
```

Problem in Chrome
[image: Problem in Chrome]

Comment: instead of set height set that as the padding-bottom to the body

Comment: good to hear! Go ahead and edit your answer and then set  it as the appropriate answer. Since you have an answer to your question that sadly is not an answer you risk getting downvoted by users or invalidating your question when in reality it is a good question. Just a lucky guess by me made it work.

Comment: I thought it worked initially, but it quickly broke by Chrome and IE. And than i thought to myself "Goodmorning!" Maybe i should not have flex shrink to 1 on the footer. So now it works in IE and Firefox as expected with the footer not collapsing. But Chrome ignores the footer and just overflow it with elements on top of the footer. Updated the thread.